# PHP search script to pull customer data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a simple search script in my own customer portal, I am trying to build it to search by their phone ESN. I am not very experienced with php, so I am probably missing something small, or making a small mistake.

anyway, when you type in any esn of a phone and hit search, it shows no results at all. here is the simple script I am working with

```
<?php
$dbserv='********';
$dbuser='********';
$dbpass='********';
$dbdata='********';
$link = mysql_connect($dbserv, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$link) {    die('Could not connect: ' .                mysql_error());}mysql_select_db($dbdata);

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">  
Search: <input type="text" name="esn" /><br />  
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>  

<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['esn'])) {

$esn = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['esn']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM phones where phoneserial LIKE '%".$esn."%'"; 
$r_query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
echo 'ESN: ' .$row['phoneserial'].'<br>';  
}  

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed I made an error earlier in this line

```
$esn = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['esn']);
```

I had it like this instead

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['esn']);
```

and then when you typed a 14 digit esn starting with A10000, it would actually show every esn in our database instead of the one that was searched for and i don't know why.

Forgive me if this is lame, still trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to find only ONE, strict match, you should replace your query with this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phones where phoneserial = '{$esn}'";
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$esn` was undefined, you'd be searching for a pure wildcard (`%%`), which would match every possible record.  Not that surprising when you look at this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phones where phoneserial LIKE '%".$esn."%'";
```

Just remove the `$esn` since you didn't define `$esn` and instead used `$term`.

You really shouldn't use mysql_ functions anymore.  Learn how to use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements rather than escape string functions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mysql`, use `Mysqli`

> **MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0**

Final well form code is

```
<?php
    $dbserv='********';
    $dbuser='********';
    $dbpass='********';
    $dbdata='********';
    $link = mysqli_connect($dbserv, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbdata);

    if (!empty($_POST['esn'])) {

        $esn = mysqli_real_escape_string($link$_POST['esn']);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM phones where phoneserial LIKE '%".$esn."%'";;
        $r_query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query))
        {
            echo 'ESN: ' .$row['phoneserial'].'<br>';
        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    Search: <input type="text" name="esn" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```